# Bringing Indian Pulses to the US?

Tags: usa, air-travel, customs-and-immigration, luggage, food-and-drink

I will be coming to the US from a country where Indian pulses are very easily available. I am coming to US for studying and thus will not have a car. I plan to cook my own food, and since the Indian store is kind of far, I would love to bring the whole year's worth of supply to US. I have the weight and space, but I was concerned about the baggage check for Moong bean and "Tuwer" daal (Daal will be split). I know that they do not allow "fresh produce" but I do not know if my food will be considered in that category. Beans will be dried and packed (though not in a tin, but in airtight plastic).

Comment: Just to clarify - you plan to enter US by air and are wondering if pulses packed in plastic bags are OK as far as customs are concerned?

Comment: I couldn't find a definitive answer for the products you specify, but the guidance [here](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1272/~/food---general-food) suggests you should be OK. However, you do have to declare all food imports and it's possible that they could be refused, in which case you'd lose your year's supply. I can't help but think that a trip to the 'kind of far' supplier once you arrive would be less trouble and less risk.

Comment: Does the ‘kind of far’ supplier offer online purchase or home delivery etc.?

Comment: @RedBaron yes for those specific pulses

Comment: @Traveller AFAIK no………but there is a trader Joe's nearby so I will have to check that

Comment: Anecdotal evidence suggests you should be OK as long as those pulses are labelled and not loosely packed (so no resealable poly packs). You can buy packs off the shelf from stores and bring them as it is. Label on packing which says what they are apparently important.

Comment: You might consider a grocery delivery service such as GrubMarket or Amazon, to see if they offer delivery from the "kind of far" supplier to your home.  Worst case, you could use Uber, Lyft, or similar service to go to the store and back.  It might be cheaper than the fees to check bags containing a year's worth.

Comment: Chickpeas are the one pulse that [can't be brought in](https://www.aphis.usda.gov/publications/plant_health/2011/KBposter-India-eng.pdf) (or rice, soybeans, or safflower seeds)

Comment: Depending where in the USA you will be living, these items might be readily available at health food and bulk food stores, or even ordinary supermarkets. Google shows tuwer dal available at Walmart(!). Dried moong beans (often spelled mung beans here) are not much harder to find than plain lentils. I would make an effort to see what is available at your destination. (Incidentally, Costco imports an excellent Indian basmati rice in 25 pound sacks.)

Comment: Amazon USA has 106 results for moong beans, you can get them delivered very easily. In my experience (~15 arrivals at USA over past 2 years), US customs/immigration officers are very anti- food of all kinds, sometimes it’s the only thing they ask about. Even if it’s allowed it’ll slow down your entry while they decide, and if you get the paperwork wrong they will fine you. I suggest don’t do it. https://www.cnn.com/2018/04/23/us/apple-delta-fine-customs-flight-500-trnd/index.html

Answer (score 4):

I advise against bringing in pulses from home.

**Air luggage restrictions**
First of all, you can not bring enough for a whole year without going over the luggage limits and that is besides whatever else you need. You claim to have the space and weight, but you will find that a years worth of pulses will take more than one suitcase. Bringing just as much as you can fit into your case without going overweight will not last you a year if you eat them regularly.

**Maybe yes, but not much**
While some foodstuffs can be brought in, there are a lot of restrictions, specially on food that can be used to grow plants, as is the case of many pulses even when packaged for food use. You would have to declare to the customs officers and they might not allow the pulses in, not declaring them and having them found on inspection will result in fines.
Mostly there are restrictions which allow some 'personal use' items, but a years amount of a basic food will be well beyond what they expect for personal use.
Declaring food on entry into the USA will slow you down some at least, it may result in all your luggage to be checked in detail, slowing you a lot.

**Availability**
There are a lot of pulses which are common food in the USA, available at all supermarkets and if you want ones that are not as common in the area you will live, you can have them delivered from online shops, including the more common ones that sell about everything, but there will be 'Indian food' online shops as well.

**Local experiences**
Last of all, part of the joys of studying abroad is learning to know the local cuisine, and while you do not need to eat everything that is common where you live, you should at least be open to some of the more common alternatives to what you are used to at home.

**In short:**
In your case I would at most pack pulses for a single week, to get you started when you arrive and you will still have to declare those at customs on arriving in the USA, and buy locally for the rest of your stay. Personal imports will not be cheaper if you need to pay overweight luggage and you do run a big risk in the food not being allowed in, having it seized at the airport.